# How Google ads add a pageview?

Tags: google-analytics, php, analytics, google-adsense

I'm having a trouble on my site. I have my own script which counts how many times the ads display in a page using PHP script, which always run every page refresh without any condition and it sums up the ads to 2 Million+ page views. but on my Google Analytics the page views is only at 100k+. 
How does the Google ads pageview works? Is it have a special condition like IP per count? or for a specific IP there is a certain x amount of time to add it to count?

Comment: Are you sure that you exclude the bots traffic from your counters? It is possible that you increase the counters when Googlebot or Bingbot or other bots are making hits to your server. Google analytics do not contain bots traffic

Comment: Ok. LOL, tnx for that additional info. I will check that. Is there other possible reasons?

Comment: I think it's bots. We had similar issues and would find some ip addresses hitting our pages hundreds of times in the span of a couple minutes. Definitely not human traffic. This would of course trigger our scripts and throw off our numbers.

Comment: Hi @drummin how did you fix it?

Comment: Ha! Not easily. We basically keep a list of all the IP addresses that we determined were bots. And for every hit to the page we would check the list and only trigger our functions if we determined it to not be a bot. Since we keep a database record for every transaction, as we found new bots, we could go back and remove them from the records.

Comment: LOL., that's a heavy one, I don't have much time to administer that. Some comments says: `preg_match('/robot|spider|crawler|curl|^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));` I will try this first. heh

Comment: That's basically how I do it to, except my match list contains dozens of ip addresses as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Google AdSense there is a IP limit.

For example if a client makes some fast hits (5 - 10), his ip is banned for a short time (1 - 2 minutes) and no more ads will be shown, or cached ads that are not counted as impressions will be served.

Also if the client uses ad blocker software (we all hate this), no ads are shown, and they are also calculated by your counter.

Finally if your pages contain errors it is also possible that not all impressions are shown on Google AdSense reports.

Google Analytics counts them all, except if client has disabled JavaScript, or a special script disable rule, which is rare.

Comment: Oh i see. it means that there is a counter for ip on how many clicks and hits/pageviews he made for a 1 specific ads. Right?

oh by the way in GA there is a 2% visitors that have a disabled javascript based on some researched by some random guy.

Comment: There is a counter to prevent spam impressions, not for each ad but for the overal hits that a visitor makes, and only for short times. For example is a visitor hits a page, and after 3 seconds he hits another page, and after 5 seconds he hits another one page and another one, he is banned for a short period to prevent spam impressions. But if you have a visitor that stays in your site 2 hours and make 400 impressions there is no problem